# Losing hover and active styles in HTML when change button background in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to do a selection bar with three buttons, in style I have hover and active, when click on a button, background color changes with a JS function, my css has no boostrap or anything like that, but when any of the three buttons get clicked, the background color changes, but hover and active have now no effect

```
    <!-- This is the bar and below css styling -->
 <div class="login_selector_container">
   <button class="login_option" id="login_option1" onclick="selectAutor()"></button>
   <button class="login_option" id="login_option2" onclick="selectEditor()"></button>
   <button class="login_option" id="login_option3" onclick="selectMiembro()"></button>
 </div>

  .login_option {
   padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
   background: white;
   border-style: none;
   font: inherit;
   transition: 0.3s;
   color: var(--mRed);
   }

  .login_option:hover {
  background: var(--mRed);
  color: white;
  }

  .login_option:active {
  background: var(--mLigthRed);
  color: white;
  }
```

And this is one of the three JS function

```
function selectEditor() {
//Changes background to white and font color to red (inactive state)
btnAutor.style.background = "white";
btnAutor.style.color = "var(--mRed)";

//Changes background to red and font color to white (active state)
btnEditor.style.background = "var(--mRed)";
btnEditor.style.color = "white";

//Changes background to white and font color to red (inactive state)
 btnMiembro.style.background = "white";
 btnMiembro.style.color = "var(--mRed)";
}
```

thanks.

Comment: It's a little difficult to reproduce this, in part because `btnAutor`, `btnEditor`, and `btnMiembro` are not included in the code you provided. Can you provide a **complete** working example that demonstrates the behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing due to the fact there is missing code in your example. The CSS in element style supersedes the class CSS so background and color in :hover wouldn't take effect. If you clear the inactive state with blank string, the :hover in the css class should work again.

```
function selectEditor() {
//Changes background to white and font color to red (inactive state)
btnAutor.style.background = "";
btnAutor.style.color = "";

//Changes background to red and font color to white (active state)
btnEditor.style.background = "var(--mRed)";
btnEditor.style.color = "white";

//Changes background to white and font color to red (inactive state)
 btnMiembro.style.background = "";
 btnMiembro.style.color = "";
}
```

Comment: Not sure why your answer wasn't upvoted. It really helped me a lot. Thanks!